# Can someone help me, I cannot find the partial derivatives of this

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

Need help find the partial derivatives...I keep keeping cos(4x-3y+z)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you explain the logic that you're applying to get that derivative?

Comment: You might be surprised to see how bad this image looks on portable devices. Consider using [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of pasting images like this. It is the community standard, and it really helps with the scalability of posts over a larger variety of devices.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate with respect to $x$.  Note that $y$ is to be regarded as a constant but $z$ is not.  So
$$\bigl(\cos(-4x-3y+z)\bigr)\Bigl(-4+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\Bigr)=0\ .$$
See if you can take it from here.

Comment: Still not understanding where to go from there

Comment: The next step is to find $\partial z/\partial x$.

Comment: is dz/dx not 0?